# Geeksources in Santiago, CL

Tags: us-citizens, chile

I've been on the look out for good hobbyist resources in Santiago.

The following is what I'm looking for followed by an example of what I would use in the U.S. (Phoenix, AZ), and the best option I've found in Santiago so far, if any.

```
Computers & Parts:
   PHX: Fry's Electronics
   SLC: PC Factory

Video Games:
   PHX: Game stop, Discount Retails (target, etc)
   SLC: MicroPlay, Lider

R/Cs:
   PHX: Duncan's R/C, Hobby Town USA
   SLC: XRC Hobbies (big win in finding this! http://www.xrchobbies.cl/)

Electronics (components, test equipment, PIC mc's, audrino, rasbPi, etc):
    PHX: Fry's Electronics (but mostly online)
    SLC: Nothing found
```

Comment: What are *R/Cs*?

Comment: A bit late, but [Mirax](http://www.mirax.cl) has lots of R/C stuff and other toys or hobby related things.

Answer (score 1):

For electronics, give it a try to MCI (http://www.olimex.cl/), Victronics (http://www.victronics.cl/) or for more basic stuff Casa Royal.